# How to stop Chrome's Node Dev Tools from focusing the window every time the app restarts?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've started my Node app with the `--inspect` flag and I'm using Chrome's Node Dev Tools at url `about:inspect`; works great.

The problem is I am also using PM2 Node process manager to watch my files and auto-restart my Node process whenever there are changes, as I normally do in development, and every time I save a file the Node Dev Tools window takes focus.

I can't find anything about this in the Dev Tools settings.

I'm on Chrome 62.0.3202.89, Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit, if that matters.

Side question: is it possible to have Chrome Dev Tools in a tab instead of a floating window? I thought this used to be possible but now I can't find the option.

Comment: I've created an issue to chromiums issue tracker here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=789317&can=4&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: note: fixed in canary (v67)

Comment: I'm running Canary 74 (also tried regular Chrome 72) and still seeing this problem. It stops in _babel-node.js every time node says "restarting due to changes". I've tried setting "never stop here", blackboxing the script, nothing helps. Any ideas?

Comment: chrome 78.0.3904.97 takes focus every time react app reloads after update. it makes me nuts. any solution yet?

Comment: Any update on this one? Is there a way to disable it? https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=789317&can=4&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified Here it is marked as fixed, but I have no idea how to get it working.